# Restrict products to purchase using Observer not trigger

Tags: event-observer, addtocart, magento1.9.2.3

Condition: I have restricted category of products [category id = 680, 894, 895], this category of products should be purchase alone, not mixed with other products.

Workout: 
Case 1: If cart had other products, if the customer tries to add restricted category products trigger observer like not eligible to add to cart and display a message like **If you want this product, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products**

case 2: If cart had a restricted category of products if customer try to add non-restricted products trigger observer like not eligible to add to cart and display a message like **Cart has Special Product you can not add another**

code :

> app/etc/modules/Gta_KolupadiRestrict.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <!-- Gta_KolupadiRestrict -->
        <Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Gta/KolupadiRestrict/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
    </modules>
    <global> 
        <models>
            <gta_kolupadirestrict>
                <class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model</class>
            </gta_kolupadirestrict>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>      
        </events>
    </global>   
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Gta/KolupadiRestrict/Model/Observer.php

```
    <?php 
    // Mage::log('fine dude', null, 'logfile.log');
    //create class

    class Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer
    {

        //create function
        public function cartevent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            // $category_id = array(680, 894, 895) ; //category ids

            // $category_products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            //                  ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('680','894','895')))
            //                  ->setWebsiteId(2);              // load website id  

            $product = $observer->getProduct();

            $category_id = $product->getCategoryIds();
            $productCatId  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                                ->setWebsiteId(2)        // load website id
                                ->load($category_id);        // load category 

            // check cart qty status                            
            $cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty();  

            //logic
            if($productCatId->getId()=='680' && $cart_qty > 0  ) //680 category id
            {
                Mage::throwException("If you want Kolu Padi, Purchase alone not mixed with other Products");    
            }

             //check if cart have products 
             $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
            {
                $productCategoryId  = $item->getCategoryIds();

                if($productCategoryId =='680')  //680 category id
                {
                    Mage::throwException("Cart has Special Product you can not add another");
                }
            }    
        }       
    }
?>
```

Observer not trigger.  Does anyone help me?

Comment: can you change the event to **`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`** and recheck?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Just i test observer working or not, observer not working, update with your code -> https://justpaste.it/4qf3f  observer.php -> https://justpaste.it/5w87x log file not created

Comment: I also checked in the latest Magento. It is not working either. I also tried other events but no success.

Comment: FYI finally found the error, Actually case sensitive codepool to codePool, now working.

Comment: I was also going to post my answer pointing the same error.

Comment: But when I rechecked your question, there was already changed from **`codepool`** to **`codePool`**. Anyway, great to know that your problem has got resolved.

Comment: Yes, just now i changed.

Answer (score 1):

In config.xml:

```
<class>Kolupadi_Restrict_Model_Observer</class>
```

should be

```
<class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer</class>
```

Change your **app/etc/modules/Gta_KolupadiRestrict.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear cache.

**[update]**

config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_KolupadiRestrict>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <gta_kolupadirestrict>
                <class>Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model</class>
            </gta_kolupadirestrict>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <gta_kolupadirestrict_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                        <class>gta_kolupadirestrict/observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </gta_kolupadirestrict_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Gta/KolupadiRestrict/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer
{
    public function cartevent($observer)
    {
        error_log('hey');
    }
}
```

Now you can see log for every add to cart press.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Mage::log('fine dude', null, 'logfile.log'); -> remove from top

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Still Not working.

Comment: Observer testing error : https://justpaste.it/7hsyp

Comment: Did you update app/etc/modules/Gta_KolupadiRestrict.xml? Here has a typo.

Comment: Yes i did, my app/etc/modules/Gta_KolupadiRestrict.xml -> https://justpaste.it/3rp4v

Comment: No, you didn't.  Check <codePool>local</codePool> line.

Comment: Yes, finally understand the  case sensitive error.

Comment: Pls check my updated post

Comment: Try simple way first. check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97089/discussion-between-zus-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: Thank you, i understand some basics about observer,

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url :

[Observer not firing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/observer-not-firing)

**I hope its work for you..**

Comment: Observer testing error https://justpaste.it/7hsyp  @Anas Mansuri