# How to load category (selected id's) in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

In my observer, i need to load my selected category id's & selected website,

workout:

```
$category_products  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('680','894','895')))
   ->setWebsiteId(2);               // load website id
```

If i compare with my cart,

```
$cart_qty = (int) Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemQty(); //get cart in observer
```

observer not triggered.

Comment: In which page you want?

Comment: cart page ->  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284297/57334

Comment: @zus can you describe what actualy you want to achive?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Here is my complete details https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284297/57334

Comment: @DhirenVasoya What event should be use before order placed for getting shipping country?